# Highlight "&lt;" and "&gt;" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: tags, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I have a lot of `&lt;` and `&gt;` (as alternatives for < and >) when writing my html files.

Which editor I need to use when I want to highlight `&lt;` and `&gt;` (lets say in yellow colour) inside Visual Studio Code?
Where is editor located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "constant.character.entity.html",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ffff00",
            }
        },
    ]
},
```